# How to use select2 component in another vue component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want a select2 component
inside another component to use it. I have imported it but can't make it work.
I have app.vue component and select2.vue component.

```
<template>   
     <select2 :options="this.options" v-model="selected">
          <option disabled value="0">Select one</option>
    </select2>
</template>
 <script>
    import select2 from 'select2'

    export default {
    name: 'app',
    data(){
            return{
            options : [
                    { id: 1, text: 'Hello' },
                    { id: 2, text: 'World' }
                ],
                selected: 1,
            }
    },
    components: {
       'select2': select2,
     }
    }
    </script>
```

I have select2 component like this:

```
<script>
    Vue.component('select2', {
        props: ['options', 'value'],
        template: '#select2-template',
        mounted: function () {
            var vm = this
            $(this.$el)
            // init select2
                .select2({ data: this.options })
                .val(this.value)
                .trigger('change')
                // emit event on change.
                .on('change', function () {
                    vm.$emit('input', this.value)
                })
        },
        watch: {
            value: function (value) {
                // update value
                $(this.$el)
                    .val(value)
                    .trigger('change')
            },
            options: function (options) {
                // update options
                $(this.$el).empty().select2({ data: options })
            }
        },
        destroyed: function () {
            $(this.$el).off().select2('destroy')
        }
    })

</script>
```

and html code like this :

I get error like this:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined"
```

I'm very new to Vuejs. I can't understand were it goes wrong. please Help me. thanks

Comment: please give more details about  your code and project structure. are you using vue cli?

Comment: I'm using Laravel mix for compiling.  I have app.vue component and select2.vue component. I edited the question.

Comment: Check the vue documentation on [integrating a 3rd party jQuery plugin (select2)](https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html)